What was done with korbanot when the Mishkan traveled?
In the wilderness the Jewish people traveled based on the movement of the cloud or pillar of fire representing God's presence (Bamidbar 9:17-23). My understanding is that the directive to travel could come at any moment. If that is the case, I would like to know what was done with korbanot which where 'in process' when the cloud lifted and it was time to go.
For example, if an animal was slaughtered but not yet butchered, was the carcass transported as is until the next camp was made and then the process resumed? If a korban was on the altar being burnt, was the fire extinguished, and was the partially burnt carcass discarded?
In sum, do any sources address what was done with korbanot when the Mishkan traveled?

https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.4.13.3?lang=bi&with=all

Did the azara have kedusha while traveling?  Did the machaneh?  Maybe they all became pasul because of yotzei.

The Gemara (Zevachim 60b-61b) discusses the point, and seems to say that it's subject to a dispute among Tannaim as to whether the korbanos become pasul at that time. I haven't looked at it in depth to understand the details, though.

Also, if blood is left out, it would congeal on the journey in the desert.
